# QT3D con C++ y rotación

Tags: c++, qt

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar con este problema. Soy nuevo trabajando con QT 3D y necesito realizar para una tarea una aplicación Qt3D usando QT C++, el problema que tengo es que necesito realizar una rotación de la figura a partir de un punto específico pero siempre me rota a partir del punto central. ¿De qué manera puedo especificar para que la rotación se realice a partir de uno de los pivotes de la figura? Lo necesito para poder simular el movimiento de un péndulo. Ayuda por favor alguién que me diga cómo puedo resolver este problema, acá les dejo mi código.

```
void window::paint(){
    arm1 = new Qt3DExtras::QCylinderMesh();
    arm1->setRadius(0.5);
    arm1->setLength(3);

    arm1Transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
    arm1Transform->setTranslation(QVector3D(-3, 3, 0));
    arm1Transform->setScale(1.5f);

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *arm1Material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
    arm1Material->setDiffuse(Qt::red);

    arm1Entity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    arm1Entity->addComponent(arm1);
    arm1Entity->addComponent(arm1Material);
    arm1Entity->addComponent(arm1Transform);
}

void window::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    arm1Transform->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), angle++));
}
```

Gracias de antemano.